# Rails install ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, installation

I am trying to install rails on my mac, but every time I type sudo gem install rails into the command line, I get the following error message. I have been stuck for a while, hope you can help.

```
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h


    Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection       
    Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to install Rails 4.0, it needs RubyGems 2.0.3, so you have to update your system by using following command

```
gem update --system 2.0.3
```

and then continue with your installation.

Hope it helped

Comment: Does this thing effect the my rails 3 application ?

Answer (score 2):

I would just use [rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install). It should work like a charm. Or you could dig around and see if you can find that ruby.h file its talking about. But I personally think the latter would be a pain in the ass.

Comment: How do we change the version of ruby using dvm? ...Sorry new to this kind of stuff.

Comment: sry. didn't see the comment until now, just do 'ruby use 2.0' or whatever version you want

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade xcode by typing following command in terminal window-

```
    xcode-select --install
```

This should solve your isssu.

Answer (score 0):

yea the rvm works like a charm and it will come in handy when you want to switch between different rails versions

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues.  I upgraded my version (using RVM) of Ruby from 2.0.0-p195 to 2.0.0-p353 (make sure you tell RVM to use the new version as the default).  After this I did `gem install rails` again and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the right version of DevKit, you can get it from here...

http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

and install as it says here:

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit#installation-instructions

Answer (score 0):

if you still have the problem even after Upgrading Xcode.
Its may be because :

The Apple LLVM compiler in Xcode 5.1 treats unrecognized command-line options as errors. This issue has been seen when building both Python native extensions and Ruby Gems, where some invalid compiler options are currently specified.

To workaround this issue, set the ARCHFLAGS environment variable to downgrade the error to a warning.

ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install GemName

Personally I have got this problem while installing json gem , I did :
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install json

And the problem was solved.